# Local Nginx reverse proxy to Laradock's Nginx

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, laradock

I have 2 websites A and B hosted on the same machine. A is an old website using `laravel`, which is containerized using `laradock`. B is a new website using `Next.js` and containerized by my self using `docker-compose`.

I've already change Nginx's port in `laradock` (website A) from **80** to **2080**.

Now I want `A.com` goes to A, `B.com` goes to B. So I installed Nginx on the machine, and set up reverse proxy.

B works just fine. However, A's static files like images, css, js is not working correctly.

I wonder if there's another workaround, or I can just twist my reverse proxy configs to make it work.

**Here's my local Nginx reverse proxy config:**

```
server {
    # SSL configuration
    
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    root /home/admin/A_src_directory;

    server_name A.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2080;
    }
```

Comment: When you say static files don't work you mean if you go to `A.com/img/abc.png` doesn't work or you mean anything resolved using `asset('/img/abc.png')` does not resolve to the correct URL ?

Comment: @apokryfos The URL resolved using `asset('')` is correct for images, css, js. 
But what's weird is images rendered correctly, css and js are not. css and js show `pending` and `blocked: mix-content`.
I feel like PHP is not working properly, maybe fastCGI config in Nginx is not proper?

Comment: Try setting `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;` as well and make sure you have configured your [trusted proxy settings](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies). It looks like Laravel is generating `http` links instead of `https`